# Next.js: Fetching external api in getStaticProps shows ETIMEDOUT error

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I fetch an external api in `getStaticProps` function and pass the api results as props to component. But when I load the page, the loading takes around 6seconds and shows error

`FetchError: request to https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=...failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 65.9.17.69:443 at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\nextjs-movie-app\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1461:11)`,

but it's not showing error everytime I load the page, sometimes I get the result but sometimes I get an error. I tested with another api and I get results instantly without an error, what am I doing wrong here ? My api call returns only 20results which success result looks like `{page: 1, results: Array(20), total_pages: 1000, total_results: 20000}`
Here is my `getStaticProps` function

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const token = "...";

  const res = await fetch(
    `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=${token}`
  );

  const data = await res.json();
  return {
    props: data,
  };
}
```

Comment: Maybe `api.themoviedb.org` times out every so often?

Comment: I think it's very unlikely, because I am sending requests from browser and refreshing but I get the results @Nathan

Comment: I suggest creating a try catch, and recursively calling the fetch request until a successful one is received. Assuming you have no control over the API

Comment: @user3875913 I've tried but it doesn't seem to work. I'll just add api calls in components for now to avoid timeout error.